# Confusion about shallow rendering in Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

The thing I want to test is some conditional rendered components:

```
import { Bar, Baz } from '@components';

const Foo = ({ isEditable, ...props }) => (
  isEditable
    ? <Bar {...props} /> // that is a <button ... >
    : <Baz {...props} /> // that is an <input ... >
);
```

My problem is with the `shallow` render of Enzyme. Isn't it supposed to NOT render the child components? But when I do `shallow(<Foo ... />)` I get `<button ... />` and not `<Bar ... />` as the content of Foo.

Is this how it should be? (And if yes, how can I test a real shallow rendering? I just want to test if the conditional rendering is working without being concerned what the child is made of.)